# Find nodes within distance in networkx and python

Tags: python, networkx

Is there a way in networkx to find all the nodes within some distance from a particular node? As in, I specify a node and a distance and get back all nodes within that distance. This is assuming that I added a weight to every edge.

Alternatively, is there a way to find all nodes within a specified degrees from a particular node? Like, what are all the nodes within 2 degrees of separation from a particular node? Degrees meaning, a node is connected to a node is connected to the node. Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the `ego_graph` function of `networkx` library:

```
node = 3 # The center node
radius = 3 # Degrees of separation
new_graph = nx.generators.ego_graph(graph, node, radius=radius)
```

For example:

```
import networkx as nx

G = nx.gnm_random_graph(n=n, m=30, seed=1)
G = nx.generators.ego_graph(G, 0, radius=2)
```

[image: Original graph]
[image: Graph centered in 0]

Answer (score 1):

This will provide a pseudo adjacency matrix, which represents adjacency within your provided radius (in degrees, not distance), not just directly linked nodes .

```
def neighbors_in_radius(G, radius):
    adj = np.array(nx.linalg.graphmatrix.adjacency_matrix(G).todense()).astype(float)  # much faster as float
    power_adj = connected = adj
    for i in range(radius - 1):
        power_adj = power_adj.dot(adj)
        connected = connected + power_adj
    connected = connected.astype(bool).astype(int)
    return connected
```

This should be significantly faster than the networkx solution in certain cases, depending on the ratio of edges to nodes, and how many nodes you want to solve for.

```
G = nx.gnm_random_graph(n=1000, m=10000, seed=1)
%time v1 = neighbors_in_radius(G, radius=2)  # 98 ms 
%time np.where(v1[n]) # 29 microsec  # to get results for specific node

%time v2 = [nx.generators.ego_graph(G, n, radius=2).nodes for n in G.nodes] # 21 sec

# confirm solutions equivalent
assert v1.sum(axis=1).tolist() == [len(x) for x in v2]
```